# Appengine Python - How to filter tab content depending if entity has been created

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a page View-Consult with 4 bootstrap tabs.

There are two entities retrieved from the Datastore on this page (Consult and Assessment). The consult is created first and the assessment later (by a different user).

Note: Consults have a property called "consult_status" that is PENDING before the Assessment is added, and COMPLETED after. This may be useful as a condition.

The properties from the Consult populate the first 3 bootstrap tabs. The Assessment properties are displayed in the 4th tab.

There will be a period where the Assessment has not been completed and the View-Consult page will need to display a message in the 4th tab saying "This consult is currently awaiting assessment. You will be notified by email when it is complete."

How would I create and test for this condition and render the appropriate output inside tab 4, depending if the Assessment is complete or not.

Note also: The Consult and Assessment have the same ID, so perhaps a better condition would be to check if there exists an Assignment with the current Consult ID. If not display message "awaiting assessment".

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the page just check if the assessment exists by retrieving it from the Consult (I imagine you store the assessment key inside the Consult).

That's it